# Why does my image not fit 100% background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my background image fit 100% screen width and hight. But it does not even show my image. Any that can tell me, what i am doing wrong.

Here you can see the code, that i've tryed. And i don't get why it dont work.

```
<section id="forside" >
      <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
      </div>
</section>

#forside {
    background: url(images/FBIlled.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

My image is not even getting showen. It's just blank. I wish that my section with id="forside" had the image FBIlled to be 100% screen width and hight. Full code can be showen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/maLYrZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even better idea:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.bg { 
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("img_girl.jpg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Put code inside div.

Taken from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp.

Comment: That was excatly what i needed! Thanks alot. Do you know why mine did not work, was that because of the body, html { height: 100%; } wasn't there?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is caused by leaving the element completely empty. Since there is nothing in the row, content, or forside div the height is 0. To fix this explicitly set the height or min-height using CSS (`height:100px` or `min-height:100px` where 100px is however big your image is).

Another problem you are having is with the actual property name, which should be `background-image: url("path/to/image.jpg")`. [This page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) has some good info on background images.

I would recommend replacing the forside divs styling with:

```
#forside {
    background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/any);
    min-height:100px;
}
```

If this works, replace the url with the path to your image, and change the min-height to one that works for you. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is due to the div being empty?
I tested adding a width and a height to your div, and the background imaged worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple.

Your section is empty & it's size is variable. Since there is no content & no size requirements the "box" is 0px x 0px it's not that the file isn't there, it's that it's so small it doesn't exist.

Edited you codepen by adding some text in there & change the image address and it works

Let me know if you have any other problems.