# Can't encode this SVG into a working background image

Tags: css, svg, sass

I have an SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="stripes" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="7" height="6" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
      <line x1="1" y="0" x2="1" y2="7" stroke="#fffa72" stroke-width="1.5" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fffeea" />
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#stripes)" />
</svg>
```

It tested it with an external tool and it works nicely:

[image]

Now I'd like to use it in background-image. I encoded the SVG with https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

[image]

I then take the encoded SVG and put it into my SCSS:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg+xmlns%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22+width%3D%22100%25%22+height%3D%22100%25%22%3E%0D%0A++%3Cdefs%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cpattern+id%3D%22stripes%22+patternUnits%3D%22userSpaceOnUse%22+width%3D%227%22+height%3D%226%22+patternTransform%3D%22rotate%2845%29%22%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Cline+x1%3D%221%22+y%3D%220%22+x2%3D%221%22+y2%3D%227%22+stroke%3D%22%23fffa72%22+stroke-width%3D%221.5%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2Fpattern%3E%0D%0A++%3C%2Fdefs%3E%0D%0A++%3Crect+width%3D%22100%25%22+height%3D%22100%25%22+fill%3D%22%23fffeea%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A++%3Crect+width%3D%22100%25%22+height%3D%22100%25%22+fill%3D%22url%28%23stripes%29%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
```

this doesn't work. the background remain empty. I know my HTML works fine because when I plug a *different* background image with a SVG I found online, it works nicely:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpattern%20id%3D%22a%22%20patternUnits%3D%22userSpaceOnUse%22%20width%3D%225%22%20height%3D%225%22%20patternTransform%3D%22rotate(45)%22%3E%3Cpath%20stroke%3D%22%23fffa72%22%20d%3D%22M1%200v5%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fpattern%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20fill%3D%22url(%23a)%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see my answer for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077571/why-does-my-image-not-fit-100-background/54077656?noredirect=1#comment94988804_54077656

Comment: This may be helpful in the future: [URL-encoder for SVG](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `xmlns` value is incorrect. It's `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, not `https://`.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpattern id='stripes' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' width='7' height='6' patternTransform='rotate(45)'%3E%3Cline x1='1' y='0' x2='1' y2='7' stroke='%23fffa72' stroke-width='1.5' /%3E%3C/pattern%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='%23fffeea' /%3E%3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='url(%23stripes)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
html, body {height: auto;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Documentation: https://www.w3.org/2000/svg - yep, with `https://` :D

In embedded `<svg>` elements most browsers default the attribute to `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` when it doesn't resolve (you can basically delete it and it still works). But they don't do it for `background-image` base64 encoded SVGs.

In short, it won't work as image if it's invalid.

Comment: Thanks. One Q: How did you produce your content? it wasn't just removing the "s" from my "https".  My original string is quite different than yours in the escaping of it. **mine**: `background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg+xmlns%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org......` **where yours starts with** `background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%25'`

Comment: guess my question to you is what process of encoding to you pass my original `svg` code through to make it work (apart from https -> http). modifying my original code and removing the 's' doesn't make the code work. but using your encoded example worked. How did you encode it?

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it if you can have a look at my comments

Comment: @Jason, I did exactly what you did (used an [online encoder](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/)), but **I did** manually change the `xmlns` from `https://` to `http://` after realizing that's the cause. (Working as embedded `<svg>` and not as image is typically because of a faulty `xmlns` so that's what I first inspected closely). Not changing `xmlns` results in a faulty result in the encoder i used, as well. I found that encoder by searching for *"svg encode base64"* and clicking on first result.

Comment: You can read about the differences between base64 encoding and URL encoding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267597/url-encode-vs-base64-encoding-usages). They are similar, but different. A `data:image/svg+xml` object should be encoded with base64, afaik. It might be possible to work with other encoding types, but URL encoders are specific for URLs, they're not for `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the answer to your exact question,
but you might make your `background` using a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) with a way simpler code:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #fff 2px, #fffa72, #fff 5px, #fff 9px, #fffa72, #fff 12px) 0 0 / 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, but I appreciate it nonetheless. My goal was to learn how to embed SVG's, but you are correct that for this particular purpose, your much simpler solution would have done the work. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

Save your svg to a file.svg and try using https://www.developertoolkits.com/base64/encoder

It takes images and turns them into data urls that you can then drop inline or in css like you are trying to do.

The website you are using is a url encoder.